# Can't find package mysqltcl - how do I install this package?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, tcl, static-libraries

How do I *load* the **mysqltlc package**?

```
thufir@mordor:~/tcl$ 
thufir@mordor:~/tcl$ tclsh mysql.tcl 
can't find package mysqltcl
    while executing
"package require mysqltcl"
    (file "mysql.tcl" line 1)
thufir@mordor:~/tcl$ 
thufir@mordor:~/tcl$ cat mysql.tcl 
package require mysqltcl
set m [mysqlconnect -user root -db mysql -password foobar]
mysqluse $m mysql
foreach res [mysqlsel $m {select host from user} -flatlist] {
    puts $res
}
mysqlclose $m
thufir@mordor:~/tcl$
```

Reference:  http://wiki.tcl.tk/6051

Comment: A little use of Google indicates that the source is [here](https://github.com/xdobry/mysqltcl)…

Answer (score 0):

thanks, yes, by installing the package tcl picked it up nicely.  I didn't know how that works for tcl.  Java uses JAR's, maven, ivy, etc, while ruby has gems...etc.

```
thufir@tleilax:~/tcl$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/tcl$ dpkg -s mysqltcl 
Package: mysqltcl
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 114
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.052-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1), tcl (>= 8.6.0-2) | tclsh
Description: interface to the MySQL database for the Tcl language
 The mysqltcl package provides a Tcl interface to the MySQL database system.
 Within Tcl you've a range of Tcl commands and a global Tcl array available
 to access the database server.
 Written in C mysqltcl uses the official MySQL C-API so that almost all
 Tcl commands correspond to MySQL C-API functions.
Original-Maintainer: Sven Hoexter <hoexter@debian.org>
Homepage: http://www.xdobry.de/mysqltcl/
thufir@tleilax:~/tcl$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/tcl$ tclsh mysql.tcl 
%
127.0.0.1
::1
localhost
localhost
tleilax
thufir@tleilax:~/tcl$
```

(on a different machine)

**IF there's a better or different way to install tcl packages, please do say so.**